# Custom Bluetooth message mBluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, bluetooth

With the following code you can pop up a window with bluetooth acces request:

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

The output of the code is the following image:

[image]

Is it possible to change the message (so not "An app wants to turn on Bluetooth", but something like "Hey can you please turn on Bluetooth?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create your own dialog with your own message and then call

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

And do not forget to declare the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission in your manifest.

Anyway, [this operation is discouraged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable())... *The enable() method is provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing system settings, such as a "power manager" app.*

Comment: I already had the Bluetooth_admin in the manifest, thanks! But with the mBluetoothAdapter.enable(), you just really enable the bluetooth. So there isn't a way where I can add a custom message and still have the "deny / allow" buttons?

Comment: Exactly, this is the reason why you should create your own dialog and enable bluetooth only after the user's confirm

Comment: Ahh, I get it now.. Do the enable when the user clicks on your custom accept button! ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is build-in Android functionality, so you would have to make a custom dialog which asks the question the way you want.

Then you would enable or disable Bluetooth programmatically based on what the users choice was.